# What causes "Could not read ToUnicode CMap in font GoogleSans-Regular"

Tags: pdf, pdfbox, apache-tika

Not sure if the problem is in the file, probably, or PDFBox or something I'm doing. I think the file.

I'm getting:

"Could not read ToUnicode CMap in font GoogleSans-Regular"

java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The start and the end values must not have different lengths.
at org.apache.fontbox.cmap.CMapParser.parseBegincodespacerange(CMapParser.java:289)
at org.apache.fontbox.cmap.CMapParser.parse(CMapParser.java:147)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.CMapManager.parseCMap(CMapManager.java:73)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.readCMap(PDFont.java:218)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.loadUnicodeCmap(PDFont.java:147)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.(PDFont.java:115)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font.(PDType0Font.java:182)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFontFactory.createFont(PDFontFactory.java:97)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources.getFont(PDResources.java:171)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.text.SetFontAndSize.process(SetFontAndSize.java:66)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:966)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStreamOperators(PDFStreamEngine.java:541)
at

ToUnicode looks like this:

```
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
12 dict begin
begincmap
/CIDSystemInfo
<</Registry (Adobe)
/Ordering (Identity)
/Supplement 0
>> def
/CMapName /Adobe-Identity-H def
CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<0000> <FFFFF>
endcodespacerange
0 beginbfchar
endbfchar
1 beginbfrange
<0003> <0037> [<0020> <0041> <0042> <0043> <0044> <0045> <0046> <0047> <0048> <0049> <004A> <004B> <004C> <004D> <004E> <004F> <0050> <0051> <0052> <0053> <0054> <0055> <0056> <0057> <0058> <0059> <005A> <0061> <0062> <0063> <0064> <0065> <0066> <0067> <0068> <0069> <006A> <006B> <006C> <006D> <006E> <006F> <0070> <0071> <0072> <0073> <0074> <0075> <0076> <0077> <0078> <0079> <007A>]
endbfrange
endcmap
CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop
end
end
```

We process a lot of third party pdfs, so my interest is more in a general way to handle this, rather than a way to repair this one file. Can I tell it to assume unicode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is at

```
<0000> <FFFFF>
```

It should be

```
<0000> <FFFF>
```

You likely won't be able to get text extraction for that font. PDFBox tries some fallback strategies but it does not always work.

Comment: Thanks! Would this prevent saving the PDF pages as images and OCRing them? I haven't tried yet, but that was suggested as a fallback.

Comment: You can still render the page.

Comment: I agree with Tilman.  Rendering will work.  If you have tesseract installed, Apache Tika should recognize missing unicode mappings and run OCR on that page automatically (may need to twiddle with settings).